# How do I increase the value of applicationIconBadgeNumber during app doesn't run?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uilocalnotification

How do I increase the applicationIconBadgeNumber by localNotification?

Is it possible to increase the applicationIconBadgeNumber to add [ 1 ] every day by localNotification?

If localNotification doesn't work, how can I change applicationIconBadgeNumber?

It was done by AppName:Count it! 
http://itunes.apple.com/app/id443809931?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

I asked a question by e-mail to the developer of this application seven months ago. 
However, a reply did not come.

```
   UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.fireDate = startDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

//I don't know the follow code.I want to increase BadgeNumber during repeatInterval     
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1++;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Answer (score 2):

Local notifications can set the application icon badge number. Obviously, the app has to run to schedule the local notification, but does not need to be running to receive it.

The other option, of course, is to use remote notifications.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am sorry that the way of speaking of a question is bad. I know LocalNotification can set the appbadge,but I don't know how to adds every [ 1 ] every day by localNotification.

Comment: SO,if you know a method different from LocalNotification(the other option),Please let me know.

Comment: Get the current value from [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] then just add 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `[UIApplication setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:]` to execute a function every X seconds (at least 600). In that function you can increase the number. 
The setKeepAliveTimeout require to be a VOIP application, so i'm not sure if apple can approve you anyway.